# Solr pivot faceting is slow unless local parameter is specified

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, facet, solrcloud

I'm running two queries on my Solr 6.6 cluster:
Slow query (50k ms):

```
http://my-solr-url.net:8983/solr/collection_name/select?indent=on&q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot=field1,field2,field3,field4&wt=json
```

Fast query (29 ms):

```
http://my-solr-url.net:8983/solr/collection_name/select?indent=on&q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot={!key=classification}field1,field2,field3,field4&wt=json
```

As we can see, the only difference is `{!key=classification}` part. I could not find explanation of this in the official Solr docs. Why would providing `key` local parameter in the query speed it up so much?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect the key local param has nothing to do with the speed up.

When you timed the queries...did you by any chance run the first (took 5s), then changed the param and run the second straight away (ook 29ms)? If you did that, your test is void, the second one is reusing work the first one did (caches, etc, and mabye the whole query was cached, not sure if that local param prevents the query cache being used).

If you want to test for real, you can for instance run each query after restarting solr.

Comment: One is consistently slow, other is consistently fast. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: if that is consistent then it warrants a bug filed in jira I guess